# Issue parsing html file with php

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have some code that parses through an html file and I stumbled across a page that contains this charcter which screwed up the parsing:
“

When I execute the following code, $len is assigned a value of 3.

```
$test = "“";
$len = strlen($test);
```

I'm suspecting that this character might be unicode.

For now I'm getting around this problem by replacing the curly double quote with a standard double quote. However I'm concerned about other files that might contain similar characters and I don't want to have replace functions for each separate instance.

How do I get php to treat this as a single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's standard string handling functions are not multi-byte aware, they stupidly count the number of bytes in the string.

If you have the [multibyte extension](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) installed, [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) is what  you are looking for.

For example, if your data is UTF-8:

```
$test = "“";
$len = mb_strlen($test, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

For unicode use php function was starts with mb_ (multibyte): For example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `mb_strlen()`, it will handle multibyte characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the multibyte version of the functions > http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php